# BreezeJS does not automatically parse numbers saved as strings with KnockoutJS bindings

Tags: validation, knockout.js, breeze

I queried my database using Breezejs using the following code:

```
viewModel = {
    products = ko.observableArray([])
};

var manager = new entityModel.EntityManager('/api/Products');
manager.executeQuery(query)
       .then(function (data) {
           viewModel.products.removeAll();
           viewModel.products(data.results);
       });
```

However the products rows contain numeric properties like Quantity which are wired to my page using the `data-bind` property. On saving the model through `manager.saveChanges()` I get a validation error. This is because KnockoutJS saves the edited numbers as strings.

What's the recommended way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of breeze v 0.80.2, this capability is now supported. ( along with the capability to customize type coercion)

Comment: Thanks, now all our custom binding handlers are useless :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a CustomBinding.

I use this for decimals:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.decimal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).blur(function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var valor = Globalize.parseFloat($(element).val());
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(value)) {
                value(valor);
                ko.bindingHandlers.decimal.update(element, valueAccessor);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).val(Globalize.format(value, "n2"));
    }
};
```

Comment: Excellent sample that will have great utility in many situations. I do think that Breeze should handle generic coercion, leaving custom KO bindings to special situations (e.g., coercing rounding to specific precision or translating custom day notations - "Today", "Yesterday", etc. - into DateTime values). Thx for this example though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question.

Currently, breeze does not attempt type coercion, but...

We have discussed having Breeze automatically attempt to coerce any values used within a set operation to the datatype of the property being set ( as defined in breeze metadata). This would occur across all binding libraries, (i.e angular, backbone etc) as well as knockout.

Please feel free to add this to the breeze [User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  We take these submissions very seriously.

Comment: I added a specific user voice for this: http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3474661-try-to-coerce-string-bindings-to-a-data-property-s

Comment: I'd definately like to see this feature added to Breeze. I just voted it up!